# How can I pass an initialized object

Tags: c++11, object, parameter-passing

Currently, in my code I have

```
vector_2 v1(1.0,2.0);
Frame.Draw( v1(2.0f,1.0f) );
```

where vector_2 is a struct with a constructor that takes 2 doubles (coordinates). Frame is an instance of some class with a function that takes a vector_2 as a parameter. This compiles just fine and the way I want.

However, when I directly try without initializing a vector prior to the function call, e.g.:

```
Frame.Draw( vector_2 v1(2.0f,1.0f) );
```

The compiler fails with the error message: expected primary-expression before v1. I was hoping to directly initialize within the function call.

I wonder if this is possible in C++, I may not know the proper syntax.

Comment: `Frame.Draw( {2.0f,1.0f} );`

Comment: This works. Thanks. Why the curly brackets? So that I can understand my mistake. Would this be also possible when initializing an object directly in a constructor, e.g. someClass::someClass():SomeOtherObject({1.0,2.0f}){...}

Comment: It's directly initializing your struct. Think of it as a way to pass arguments that can be used to construct the `vector_2` needed by the function call.

Comment: You could also use `Frame.Draw(vector_2(2.0f,1.0f));`; this is the same as your second example, except without the `v1`.  This is more verbose than uniform initialisation (what AndyG used), though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are declaring a variable inside a a call:

```
Frame.Draw( vector_2 v1(2.0f,1.0f) );
```

You have to do this, which instead of declaring a variable declares a temporary directly inside Frame.Draw:

```
Frame.Draw( vector_2{2.0f, 1.0f});
```

or

```
Frame.Draw( vector_2(2.0f, 1.0f));
```

depending on how you declared things. Be careful with initialization in C++, it is quite confusing, for some gotchas and general working take a look here:

- https://mbevin.wordpress.com/2012/11/16/uniform-initialization/
- https://probablydance.com/2013/02/02/the-problems-with-uniform-initialization/